# Why do I have to compose id with mapM

Tags: haskell

I have the following methods:

```
nucleotideComplement :: Char -> Either String Char
nucleotideComplement 'G' = Right 'C'
nucleotideComplement 'C' = Right 'G'
nucleotideComplement 'T' = Right 'A'
nucleotideComplement 'A' = Right 'U'
nucleotideComplement x = Left "Not a valid RNA nucleotide."
```

And would like to define another:

```
toRNA :: String -> String
toRNA = either error mapM nucleotideComplement
```

However I'm getting a type error here. However doing it this way seems to fix the issue:

```
toRNA :: String -> String
toRNA = either error id . mapM nucleotideComplement
```

I don't understand why this happens

First, `id` has the type `a -> a`. Next, when getting the type (`:t`) of `mapM nucleotideComplement` and `id . mapM nucleotideComplement`, they seem to be the same. Why am I getting such a different effect?

Hope someone could clarify this further.

Comment: Shouldn't the error say "Not a valid **DNA** nucleotide", since the valid inputs are GCTA?

Comment: That is actually a great observation. I will correct it appropriately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of either is `(a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c`. So you apply it to `error` and you get `(b -> c) -> Either String b -> c`, then you apply that to `mapM` and you get `Monad m => Either String (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`. Then you apply that to `nucleotideComplement` and you get an error because `nucleotideComplement` is a function and not an `Either`.

In other words you apply `either` to three arguments when you intended to call it with two arguments where the second argument was the result of applying `mapM` to `nucleotideComplement`. To call the function with the arguments you intended, you can write `either error (mapM nucleotideComponent)`, but that still won't work because the second argument to `either` should be a function accepting a `Char` (because you have an `Either String Char`), not one accepting a monad. To achieve what you wanted you can either write `either error nucleotideComponent` or use `.` as you already found out.

The version with `.` works because the precedence rules of Haskell say that `either error id . mapM nucleotideComplement` is equivalent to `(either error id) . (mapM nucleotideComplement)`, not `(either error id . mapM) nucleotideComplement` or `either error (id . mapM nucleotideComplement)`. `either error id` is a function that turns an `Either String b` into an `Either a b` where the left case would cause an error and `mapM nucleotideComplement` is a function that turns an `m Char` into another `m Char` with the char being "flipped" for any monad m - in this case `m` being `Either String`. So by composing these two functions, you get a function that turns an `Either String Char` into an `Either a Char` with the right case being a flipped char and the left case causing an error.

Of course `either error flipNucleotide` is the far simpler solution.

Answer (score 12):

I think you're reading this wrong...

```
either error id . mapM nucleotideComplement
```

You seem to think this means

```
either error (id . mapM nucleotideComplement)
```

when in fact it means

```
(either error id) . (mapM nucleotideComplement)
```

You aren't doing `id . mapM nucleotideComplement` anywhere. You're applying `mapM` and then passing the result to `either`, which will apply `error` or `id` depending on whether it sees `Left` or `Right`.

Comment: This was very helpful. I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly get at your type error, but I'd like to suggest that you reconsider your representation. Specifically, it's generally best to use types to enforce invariants, avoiding partial functions that can throw errors or exceptions, and avoiding accidentally mixing up related things that may belong to different parts of the code. There are various ways to approach this, but here's one. This approach pretends that DNA and RNA have completely different kinds of nucleotides. Chemically, this is not true, but it's probably a sensible representation for what you're doing. Actually encoding the chemical reality is probably beyond the abilities of Haskell's type system, and probably actually less useful for catching mistakes in this context.

```
data DNANucleotide = GD | CD | TD | AD
data RNANucleotide = GR | CR | UR | AR

toStringDNA :: [DNANucleotide] -> String
toStringDNA = map (\nucleotide -> case nucleotide of
  {GD -> 'G'; CD -> 'C'; TD -> 'T'; AD -> 'A'})

toStringRNA = ...

fromCharDNA :: Char -> Maybe DNANucleotide
fromCharDNA 'G' = Just GD
fromCharDNA 'C' = Just CD
...
fromCharDNA _ = Nothing

fromCharRNA = ...

fromStringDNA :: String -> Maybe [DNANucleotide]
fromStringDNA = mapM fromCharDNA

fromStringRNA :: String -> Maybe [RNANucleotide]
fromStringRNA = mapM fromCharRNA
```

Once you get into the actual mechanics of *working* with DNA and RNA, as opposed to reading them in from strings, there can be no more errors:

```
transcribeN :: DNANucleotide -> RNANucleotide
transcribeN GD = CR
transcribeN CD = GR
transcribeN TD = AR
transcribeN AD = UR

transcribe :: [DNANucleotide] -> [RNANucleotide]
transcribe = map transcribeN
```